# HTML, Javascript - input date as DD/MM

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering, is there any way to create an input in format "DD/MM"?

I tried this, but knew it shouldn't work:

```
var question5  = "<div id='2'><p>Start of the fiscal year</p><br>" 
                   + "<input type=\"date\" id=\'startdate\' placeholder=\"dd/mm\"></input><br></div>";
```

I am adding the element using `document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML += question`.

Could you, please, help me with it?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Why are you escaping `'` in startdate?  I would expect you'll get `\'`  instead and end up with invalid html

Comment: @barrycarter the input field is in "DD/MM/YYYY" format, that's why it doesn't work for me :)

Comment: @KScandrett well don't have any errors

Comment: You may not have errors but if you have a look at the html produced it is probably not what you intended

Comment: There is no input `type` that would use the format you want; you will have to use a normal `text` input instead, and then add whatever else logic/features you need it to have, using custom code. "Input mask" would be one keyword for solutions that help to ensure the data is entered in the correct format. If you also need some sort of date picker functionality, you will have to add that yourself as well.